# How do I style 2 different elements based on one :checked value?

Tags: html, css

I have a set of radio buttons custom-styled for a quiz that I'm creating. The 'normal' state displays fine, but the issue I'm having is changing the style (colour) for the 'checked' state.

Each of the newly style 'choices' contains 2 span's to allow for the numbering to show in a coloured box and the text to show in a white box. When a 'choice' is clicked, I have it so that the the coloured numbering box changes like it should, but can't figure out how to change the border colour of the 2nd span at the same time.

You can see exactly what I mean here: https://jsfiddle.net/2cs9n7yo/

Essentially I want to be able to change the value of colour properties within both .left-col and .right-col -- .left-col works fine, but I'm not sure how to do it for .right-col as well as when I tried just setting it up the same way, it didn't work properly. Is there a way to change properties within 2 different elements based on :checked?

```
 /*This part works*/
 .container input:checked + .left-col{
     background:#a20067;
     border:2px solid #a20067;
 }

/*This doesn't do anything*/
.container input:checked + .right-col{
   border:2px solid #a20067;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did not look at the code, is the element the next sibling after the checkbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` is an [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors). You need to use a `~` selector with `.right-col` since it isn't adjacent to the checked input. `~` is a [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) and will select any `.right-col` that comes after the `:checked` element.

```
.container input:checked ~ .right-col{
   border:2px solid #a20067;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2cs9n7yo/1/

Comment: Thank you so much for not only providing the solution so quickly, but also for taking the time to provide the explanation. I wasn't aware that + was for adjacent only and ~ was for a sibling, so that was extremely helpful. Thanks!!

Comment: @Mark you're welcome. You could use `~` for them both, too, if you wanted to keep it consistent.